# What is difference between pass by ref and pass by val in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

what is difference between pass by ref and pass by val in systemverilog?

I just want to know what is difference between `pass by ref` and `pass by val` in systemverilog?

I can't find any example.also expecially, what is this? Does anyone know what is this and explain?

```
 interface xxx
  ...
 event yyy;
 event ggg;

 modport io_bus ( ref yyy,
                  ref ggg,
                  ....
                 );
 endinterface
```

What is the purpose "ref yyy" in the modport ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pass by value**

In SystemVerilog, Pass by value is the default mechanism for passing arguments to subroutines. This argument passing mechanism works by copying each argument into the  subroutine area. If the subroutine is automatic, then the subroutine retains a local copy of the arguments in its stack.

**Pass by reference**

Arguments passed by reference are not copied into the subroutine area, rather, a reference to the original argument is passed to the subroutine.

The subroutine can then access the argument data via the reference. No casting shall be permitted.

Also note, It shall be illegal to use argument passing by reference for subroutines with a lifetime of static.

Only the following shall be legal to pass by reference:

```
— A variable,
— A class property,
— A member of an unpacked structure, or
— An element of an unpacked array.
```

Nets and selects into nets shall not be passed by reference

For your question

> What is the purpose "ref yyy" in the modport ?

There are some performance improvement when you use reference to an event when different events gets triggered multiple times, but it is a good practice to use only when considerable performance optimizations are required/necessary. One recommended example to use pass by reference can be found in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23395900/1970427)

Here I've shown one way of how modport with ref event is used.

```
interface intf(input clk);
event out_event;
  logic clk;
  modport dut(input clk,ref out_event);  
  always @(out_event)
    $display ($time,"ns"," out_event triggered");
endinterface

module dut( intf.dut d);
  reg [2:0] count;
  initial
    count = 0;
  always @ (posedge d.clk)begin
    count = count + 1'b1;
    if ( count == 'd2)
      -> d.out_event;
      end
endmodule

module top (input clk);
  intf int_f(.clk(clk));
  dut u0(.d(int_f.dut));
endmodule
```

The above working example can be found in the link [EDA-Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/J3J)

For more details about **Pass by value** refer Section 13.5.1 of SystemVerilog LRM [IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) and for **Pass by reference** refer Section 13.5.2

Comment: What is your point of the example? When I just use inout out_event instead ref, I can not find any differnece.

Comment: The point in the example is for your question "I can't find any example, what is this?" and "A ref argument is similar to an inout argument except that an inout argument is copied twice: once from the actual into the argument when the subroutine is called and once from the argument into the actual when the subroutine returns." again I have mentioned the difference which comes to performance. Note that a ref cannot be qualified with  a directional qualifier.

Answer (score 1):

The two code blocks below summarize the difference.

```
value = 1;
IncreaseByOne(ref value); //pass by reference
//value will be set to 2

value = 1;
IncreaseByOne(value); //pass by value
//value will still be 1
```

Passing by reference means that the method which gets the parameter is able to change the variable such that the original variable is also changed. Passing by value means that a copy of the value is passed, and any change to that copy does not reflect back on the original variable.

Comment: Tanks for letting me know about both difference. But especially there are used ' event'  not just variable.  Then how can you explain it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Verilog myself, in some languages data types can only be passed by reference (java/c#). 
You can create an example that passes an event using the ref keyword, and one that doesn't use the ref keyword. Then make a change to the event. Afterwards you can check if the original event was changed or not.